# Score counter doesn't increment

Tags: java, android

i just wondering if my code is right because my score counter is not increasing here is my code

```
result=ans*ans2;
holdV=(Integer.parseInt(mystr));
Boolean b=(holdV==result);
int i=0;
if(b){
  i++;
  score.setText(""+i);
}
```

whenever i run my application, it moves to one and then it stop increasing even though you got the correct answer. this is an android application implementation.

Comment: is b true/false? and what value do you get for score.setText(??)

Comment: b is true and then the value of score is the incremented value of i.

Answer (score 5):

You always set the value to 0 here:

```
int i=0; // <--set to 0
if(b){
  i++; // <-- increment: result will be 1
  score.setText(""+i);
}
```

You should have i declared and initialized outside the loop, something like this:

```
int i=0;
while(someCondition) {

 //.. code, acquiring answer, etc

  result=ans*ans2;
  holdV=(Integer.parseInt(mystr));
  Boolean b=(holdV==result);

  if(b){
    i++; // <-- increment: result will be 1
    score.setText(""+i);
  }

}
```

Comment: To solve, move this `i` in field declaration or outside of this scope.

Comment: @Glenn I think that depends on the problem solved. This seems to be a run of the mill homework question, the most likely solution is lighter in weight: I suggested just mocing it outside of the loop

Answer (score -1):

use while loop instead of if (just answer to your question)

```
result=ans*ans2;
holdV=(Integer.parseInt(mystr));
Boolean b=(holdV==result);
int i=0;
while(b){
  i++;
  score.setText(""+i);
}
```

Comment: @ppeterka66 I just given where the error was occurred... and question not full... so how can u give while loop, i think it your answer will not work properly without knowing the correct values of mystr, ans, ans2, hold

Comment: I disagree. In this current form your answer can **never function properly**, regardless what the conditions surrounding the code are. The significant difference between my and your answer is that _assuming the proper conditions_ (e.g. values of other variables) my _can_ operate properly. What your code does in case `b` is true: increments `i`, and prints a line, until the end of the world. **There is no normal way of breaking the loop**, as `b` is a local variable. I think this outcome is not the desired one.